# ULTRA simple JQuery not working - Adding a single class

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm a complete noob at JQuery, CSS and all this stuff. I'm trying to do something more complex but the very first step is already failing, for some bewildering reason. All I am trying to do right now is add a class to certain elements. I have reduced the problem to a minimum reproducible example. Here is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ZeHgS/8of76kcL/31/

My code is simply:

```
$("li").addClass("cat-parent");
```

But nothing happens at all. None of the LI have this class after I run it.

What I ultimately wanted to do was something a bit more complex:

```
$("li.wc-block-product-categories-list-item:has(ul.wc-block-product-categories-list)").addClass("cat-parent");
```

Not sure if the syntax is correct but nothing happens when I try that either.

So, in words, what I really want is to add `.cat-parent` to all LI that have ULs of a specific class. The actual ULs have one other class in addition to the one that I used above, but this extra class has different numbers at the end for each UL. Does it also need to be included for the selection to work? If so, would it be written as I have below?

```
$("li.wc-block-product-categories-list-item:has(ul.wc-block-product-categories-list[class^=\"wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-categories-list--depth-1\")").addClass("cat-parent");
```

The full UL classes are something like `wc-block-product-categories-list[class^="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-categories-list--depth-1`, where the number at the end varies.

Why on earth is this simple code not working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before run Jquery please add Jquery library, please add and check it again it is working

Comment: Oh my goodness, I feel so silly. This is my first time using JSFiddle. I would have spent 100 million hours trying to get this to work. Thank you so much!